# C# and UTF-16 characters

Tags: c#, unicode

Is it possible in C# to use UTF-32 characters not in Plane 0 as a char?

```
string s = ""; // valid
char c = ''; // generates a compiler error ("Too many characters in character literal")
```

And in s it is represented by two characters, not one.

Edit: I mean, is there a character AN string type with full unicode support, UTF-32 or UTF-8 per character? For example if I want a for loop on utf-32 (maybe not in plane0) characters in a string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) class represents a UTF-16 encoded block of text, and each [`char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) in a `string` represents a UTF-16 code value.

Although there is no BCL type that represents a single Unicode code point, there is support for Unicode characters beyond Plane 0 in the form of method overloads taking a `string` and an index instead of just a `char`. For example, the static [`GetUnicodeCategory`﻿`(char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6sx68ke.aspx) method on the [System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.aspx) class  has a corresponding [`GetUnicodeCategory`﻿`(string,int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a91e3zb6.aspx) method that will recognize a simple character or a surrogate pair starting at the specified index.

---

To iterate through the text elements in a `string`, you can use the methods on the [System.Globalization.StringInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.aspx) class. Here, a "text element" corresponds to a single character as displayed on screen. This means that simple characters (`"a"`), combining characters (`"a\u0304\u0308"` = "ā̈"), and surrogate pairs (`"\uD950\uDF21"` = "��") will all be treated as a single text element.

Specifically, the [GetTextElementEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2f3k4f6.aspx) static method will allow you to enumerate over each text element in a `string` (see the linked MSDN page for a code example).

Comment: Good presentation of the facts. Note that C# allows you to use `"\U00064321"` (exactly eight hexadecimal digits after the `\U`) which is equivalent to `"\uD950\uDF21"` but easier to "understand" from a Unicode/UTF-32 point of view. This is a code point in [plane 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Unassigned_planes).

Comment: While this is correct at the time of writing, I'd like to add for future reference that there is now a type which represents a UNICODE Scalar Value: Rune.

Answer (score 4):

I only know this problem from Java and checked the [documentation on `char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x9h8tsay%28VS.80%29.aspx) before answering and indeed the behavior is pretty much the same in .NET/C# and Java.

It seems that indeed a `char` is defined to be 16 bit and definitely can't hold anything outside of Plane 0. Only `String`/`string` is capable of handling those characters. In a `char`-array it will be represented as [two surrogate characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

Answer (score 3):

C# System.String support UTF-32 just fine, but you can't iterate through the string like it is an array of System.Char or use IEnumerable.

for example:

```
// iterating through a string NO UTF-32 SUPPORT
for (int i = 0; i < sample.Length; ++i)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(sample[i]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IsDigit");
    }
    else if (Char.IsLetter(sample[i]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IsLetter");
    }
}

// iterating through a string WITH UTF-32 SUPPORT
for (int i = 0; i < sample.Length; ++i)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(sample, i))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IsDigit");
    }
    else if (Char.IsLetter(sample, i))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IsLetter");
    }

    if (Char.IsSurrogate(sample, i))
    {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Note the subtle difference in the Char.IsDigit and Char.IsLetter calls.  And that String.Length is always the number of 16-bit "characters", not the number of "characters" in the UTF-32 sense.

Off topic, but UTF-32 support is completely unnecessary for an application to handle international languages, unless you have a specific business case for an obscure historical/technical language.

Comment: What you're talking about is not UTF-32, it's just UTF-16 that happens to contain supplemental characters. In UTF-32, every character is stored as four bytes. .NET strings are always UTF-16.

Comment: Instead of "with UTF-32 support", the example should probably read "with surrogate pair support" or "with support for actual characters, not just 16-bit chunks of I-hope-this-char-is-in-the-BMP".