# Creating an array of all ASCII characters in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, ascii

I am currently creating a program that uses arrays to categorize ASCII characters in a text document. I am stuck when it comes to creating the array itself, which is a critical part to the project's functionality. It is also suggested that I make the array out of charfrequency objects, which I know my code for is not quite right for this particular project. I used the code from another similar project, but am unsure how to translate it to a project that reads text from a file. I have included my charfrequency class code for reference as to a general idea of what I'm trying to do. I also need to display the results in a format like this:

```
H(72) = 1
e(101) = 1
l(108) = 2
o(111) = 1
.(46) = 1
```

I do not understand programming very well, so detailed explanations with relatively simple terms would be very helpful.

```
{
public class CharFrequency
{
    private char m_character;
    private long m_count;

    public CharFrequency(char ch)
    {
        Character = ch;
        Count = 0;
    }

    public CharFrequency(char ch, long charCount)
    {
        Character = ch;
        Count = charCount;
    }

    public char Character
    {
        set
        {
            m_character = value;
        }

        get
        {
            return m_character;
        }
    }

    public long Count
    {
        get
        {
            return m_count;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                value = 0;

            m_count = value;
        }
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        m_count++;

    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        bool equal = false;
        CharFrequency cf = new CharFrequency('\0', 0);

        cf = (CharFrequency)obj;

        if (this.Character == cf.Character)
            equal = true;

        return equal;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return m_character.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        String s = String.Format("Character '{0}' ({1})'s frequency is {2}", m_character, (byte)m_character, m_count);

        return s;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: I don't see _any_ questions here.

Answer (score 7):

Since Unicode  matches ASCII codes you can just select ASCII range with `Enumerable.Range`:

```
var allAscii = Enumerable.Range('\x1', 127).ToArray();
```

Note that C#/.Net uses UTF-16 ([C# and UTF-16 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697055/c-sharp-and-utf-16-characters)) to represent `char`, but if you only looking for ASCII range it is not a problem (as [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) covers characters with codes 1-127 it will not conflict with surrogate pairs which are encoded into 2 `char` in a string).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store your character frequencies in `Dictionary<char, long>`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to look at this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665757/c-sharp-convert-char-to-int
```

If it were me I would create an array in which I stored the character occurances like this:

```
long[] charCount = new long[256];
```

And then each time I see a character convert it to its integer value with something like:

```
int idx = (int)char.GetNumericValue(c);
```

And then count that character occurance like:

```
charCount[idx]++;
```

Comment: This appears to be more along the lines of what the OP is looking for.

Comment: The ASCII subset of Unicode is codepoints 0-127. So, the array only needs to have 128 elements.